# update the campaignmember when case lookupfield -TRUE

Tags: trigger

i have a requirement to  display teh count of lookups peformed on each case under a campaign.
SO iam trying to update a custom filed(number) on campaign member when tthe case has lookup filed value=TRUE.

i need help in how to update the camapign member custom filed

Comment: Your requirement does not seem well thought out. How do you know which Campaign member to update? Where is the custom field located, how are they related? What is the ultimate goal (better defined)

Comment: There si look up relation between case and camapign member .

Comment: custom fied is on campaign member.Goal is to show the number of lookups  on a camapign (a check box on case ) .Case is related to camapign  member through look up relation